# Which hooks should I implement in Drupal 7 that are the equivalent of hook_comment() and hook_nodeapi()?

Tags: 7, hooks

This is the code I am using for Drupal 6:

```
/**
 * @Implement of hook_nodeapi()
 */
function mycaptcha_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
  global $user;
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
      if (isset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key']);
      }
    break;
    case 'validate':
      if ($node->mycaptcha_ask) {

        mycaptcha_ask_form_validate($node->mycaptcha_ask);
      }
    break;
  }
}

/**
 * @Implement of hook_comment()
 */
function mycaptcha_comment(&$comment, $op) {
  global $user;
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
      if (isset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key']);
      }
    break;
    case 'validate':
      if ($comment['mycaptcha_ask']) {
        mycaptcha_ask_form_validate($comment['mycaptcha_ask']);
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

What are the equivalent hooks that I should implement for Drupal 7, to obtain code equivalent to the one I am actually using for Drupal 6?

**from kiamlaluno's help. i changed the code to the following. but the validation still doesn't work. but the above code(hook_comment) works ok under drupal 6.**

what's wrong with my code in drupal 7.

```
function mycaptcha_comment_insert($comment) {  
  global $user;
      if (isset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key']);
      }
   }

function mycaptcha_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mycaptcha_comment_validate';
}

function mycaptcha_comment_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
      if ($comment['mycaptcha_ask']) {
        mycaptcha_ask_form_validate($comment['mycaptcha_ask']);
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will reply to your question basing on the value for `$op` shown in your code snippet.

#### `hook_nodeapi()`, "insert"

The equivalent for Drupal 7 is [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), which receives just one parameter: `$node`.

#### `hook_nodeapi()`, "validate"

The equivalent for Drupal 7 is [hook_node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7), which receives three parameters: `$node`, `$form`, `&$form_state`.
The implementations of `hook_node_validate()` don't usually use the last parameter, but they check the values of the properties for the `$node` object.

#### `hook_comment()`, "insert"

The equivalent of that hook, in Drupal 7, is [hook_comment_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7), which receives the comment object as unique parameter.

#### `hook_comment()`, "validate"

Unfortunately, in Drupal 7 there isn't `hook_comment_validate()`; you need to add a validation handler for the comment form.

```
function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_comment_validate';
}

function mymodule_comment_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  /**
   * Validate the comment.
   * $form_state['values']['name'] is the name of the user who wrote the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['is_anonymous'] is TRUE if the user is anonymous (not logged in);
   * $form_state['values']['mail'] is the email address of who wrote the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['homepage'] is the URL of the website of who wrote the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['subject'] is the title of the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['comment'] is the text of the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['language'] is the language associated with the comment;
   * $form_state['values']['uid'] is the user ID of who wrote the comment.
   * $form_state['comment'] is the comment object.
   */
}
```

Notice that `mymodule_comment_validate()` doesn't get any `$comment` parameter, and `$form_state['comment']` is an object, not an array. You are using a `$comment` variable that is not defined, nor is one of the parameters.

The code I wrote works independently from the content type of the node where the comment appears. In Drupal 7, the hooks called to alter a form build from another module are `hook_form_alter()`, `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`, `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. The base form ID for the comment form is "comment_form."
If you just need to alter the comment form for a specific content type (e.g. the "Article" content type), then you replace `mymodule_form_comment_form_alter()` with `mymodule_form_comment_node_article_form_alter()`.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/224333#remove_op).

Specifically, [`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), [`hook_node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7), [`hook_comment_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7), and [`comment_form_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_form_validate/7) (see [`commment_validate()` removed](http://drupal.org/node/224333#comment_validate_removed)).